# Running MPI on two hosts

Tags: cluster-computing, mpi

I've looked through many examples and I'm still confused. I've compiled a simple latency check program from [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_latency.c), and it runs perfectly on one host, but when I try to run it on two hosts it hangs. However, running something like `hostname` runs fine:

```
[hamiltont@4 latency]$ mpirun --report-bindings --hostfile hostfile --rankfile rankfile -np 2 hostname
[4:16622] [[5908,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[5908,1],0] to slot_list 0
4
[5:12661] [[5908,0],1] odls:default:fork binding child [[5908,1],1] to slot_list 0
5
```

But here is the compiled latency program:

```
[hamiltont@4 latency]$ mpirun --report-bindings --hostfile hostfile --rankfile rankfile -np 2 latency 
[4:16543] [[5989,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[5989,1],0] to slot_list 0
[5:12582] [[5989,0],1] odls:default:fork binding child [[5989,1],1] to slot_list 0
[4][[5989,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:638:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 10.0.2.5 failed: Connection timed out (110)
```

My current guess is that there is something wrong with my firewall rules (e.g. hostname does not communicate between hosts, but the latency program does).

```
[hamiltont@4 latency]$ cat rankfile
rank 0=10.0.2.4 slot=0
rank 1=10.0.2.5 slot=0
[hamiltont@4 latency]$ cat hostfile 
10.0.2.4 slots=2
10.0.2.5 slots=2
```

Comment: That's the `tcp` BTL component trying to establish a connection between node `4` and node `5` in order to start sending messages and failing. You analysis is correct - `hostname` doesn't do MPI communication and that's why it works fine. Simply instruct your firewalls to both accept connections from the other host.

Comment: Hristo - if you would reply as an answer I'd be happy to accept it! turning off IPTables inside the lan worked fine!

Comment: There you go - an answer to your specific question and some additional information that might come handy for others that experience the same problem but for a different reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two kinds of communication involved in running an Open MPI job. First the job has to be launched. Open MPI uses a special framework to support many kinds of launches and you are probably using the `rsh` remote login launch mechanism over SSH. Obviously your firewall is correctly set up to allow SSH connections.

When an Open MPI job is launched and the processes are true MPI programs, they connect back to the `mpirun` process that spawned the job and learn all about the other processes in the job, most importantly the available network endpoints at each process. This message:

```
[4][[5989,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:638:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 10.0.2.5 failed: Connection timed out (110)
```

indicates that the process which runs on host `4` is unable to open a TCP connection to the process which runs on host `5`. The most common reason for that is the presence of a firewall, which limits the inbound connections. So checking your firewall is the first thing to do.

Another common reason is if on both nodes there are additional network interfaces configured and up, with compatible network addresses, but without the possibility to establish connection between them. This often happens on newer Linux setups where various virtual and/or tunnelling interfaces are being brought up by default. One can instruct Open MPI to skip those interfaces by listing them (either as interface names or as CIDR network addresses) in the `btl_tcp_if_exclude` MCA parameter, e.g.:

```
$ mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_exclude "127.0.0.1/8,tun0" ...
```

(one always have to add the loopback interface if setting `btl_tcp_if_exclude`)

or one can explicitly specify which interfaces to be used for communication by listing them in the `btl_tcp_if_include` MCA parameter:

```
$ mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 ...
```

Since the IP address in the error message matches the address of your second host in the hostfile, then the problem must come from an active firewall rule.

Comment: Agreed, and sweet answer! The simple fix for us was to disable iptables within our LAN

Comment: Same issue here. MPI code would fail and throw the same error about the connection timing out. The fix of disabling the firewall on the machines resolved the issue.

Comment: including the interface works for me, but is there a way to find out which interface is used erroneously?

Comment: @Jounathaen Take the IP from the error message and compare it against the node's routing table.