# Cluster hangs/shows error while executing simple MPI program in C

Tags: networking, network-programming, cluster-computing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to run a simple MPI program(multiple array addition), it runs perfectly in my PC but simply hangs or shows the following error in the cluster.
I am using open mpi and the following command to execute

#### Netwok Config of the cluster(master&node1)

```
            MASTER
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:A4:52:74  
          inet addr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:19ff:fea4:5274/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16914 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2050581 (1.9 MiB)  TX bytes:981632 (958.6 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:A4:52:76  
          inet addr:192.168.41.203  Bcast:192.168.41.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:19ff:fea4:5276/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:75457 (73.6 KiB)  TX bytes:25295 (24.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:88362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:88362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:21529504 (20.5 MiB)  TX bytes:21529504 (20.5 MiB)

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:A4:52:74  
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:19ff:fea4:5274/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2373869 (2.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1020320 (996.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:da000000-da012800 

peth1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:A4:52:76  
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:19ff:fea4:5276/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:168837 (164.8 KiB)  TX bytes:33241 (32.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:d6000000-d6012800 

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:E3:80:BC  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
            
                NODE 1
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:53:42:C6  
          inet addr:10.1.255.253  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7299 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1898811 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:1056294 (1.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3114 (3.0 KiB)  TX bytes:3114 (3.0 KiB)

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:19:53:42:C6  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16913 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7276 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2221627 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:1076708 (1.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f8000000-f8012800 

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:E7:E5:FF  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

#### Error

```
mpirun -machinefile machine -np 4 ./query
error code:
[[22877,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:638:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 192.168.122.1 failed: Connection refused (111)
```

#### Code

```
#include    <mpi.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#define     group           MPI_COMM_WORLD
#define     root            0
#define     size            100

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int no_tasks,task_id,i;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(group,&no_tasks);
MPI_Comm_rank(group,&task_id);
int arr1[size],arr2[size],local1[size],local2[size];
if(task_id==root)
{
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr1[i]=arr2[i]=i;
    }
}
MPI_Scatter(arr1,size/no_tasks,MPI_INT,local1,size/no_tasks,MPI_INT,root,group);
MPI_Scatter(arr2,size/no_tasks,MPI_INT,local2,size/no_tasks,MPI_INT,root,group);
for(i=0;i<size/no_tasks;i++)
{
    local1[i]+=local2[i];
}
MPI_Gather(local1,size/no_tasks,MPI_INT,arr1,size/no_tasks,MPI_INT,root,group);
if(task_id==root)
{       
    printf("The Array Sum Is\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",arr1[i]);
    }
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Connection refused is from the network, so it sounds like the configuration of the cluster is the problem.

Comment: Possibly firewall issue? Like Fred says, it's a network issue, not an `mpi` issue as such.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072563/running-mpi-on-two-hosts/15073717). You question might be a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Fred I have added the network config of the cluster, I am working on. master and first nodes IPV6 addresses are on the same subnet could that be a problem

Comment: @MatsPetersson single scatter works between master and slaves ,so firewall allows a single access for sure + there is a passwordless SSH connetion between them

Comment: Did you read the question that I linked to? Because my answer there is the answer to your problem. Anyway, I've adapted it to your case and posted an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell Open MPI not to use the virtual bridge interface `virbr0` interface for sending messages over TCP/IP. Or better tell it to only use `eth0` for the purpose:

```
$ mpiexec --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 ...
```

This comes from the greedy behaviour of Open MPI's `tcp` BTL component that transmits messages using TCP/IP. It tries to use all of the available network interfaces that are up on each node in order to maximise the data bandwidth. Both nodes have `virbr0` configured with the same subnet address. Open MPI falls to recognise that both addresses are equal, but since the subnets match, it assumes that it should be able to talk over `virbr0`. So process A is trying to send a message to process B, which resides on the other node. Process B listens on port `P` and process A knows this, so it tries to connect to `192.168.122.1:P`. But this is actually the address given to the `virbr0` interface on the node where process A is, so the node tries to talk to itself on a non-existent port, hence the "connection refused" error.