# MPICH process frozen without any error message nor warning

Tags: centos, mpi, mpich

I am trying to run a meteorological simulation with RAMS model (http://vandenheever.atmos.colostate.edu/vdhpage/rams.php) in a new cluster with CentOs7 in all nodes. We have other applications running fine in the cluster, sending processes to each node,... everything seemd to run fine.

But the RAMS model freezes at its first stage on the parallel run. RAMS developers recommend using mpich2-1.4.1 as they have successfully tested. If I try to run a parallel simulation in the master node it runs fine and starts the required number of processes. If I try to use the other nodes the simulation freezes, do not stop with any error message; RAMS model processes appear in all used nodes and in the master node but any output is created and the usual status messages from RAMS do not appear on screen.

The commnad line to run the model is

```
[paco@Llamp RUN]$ time ../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/mpirun -verbose -machinefile mpd.hosts -n 20 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN
```

I have also compiled and tried to run with mpich 3.0.4 but it behaves exactly the same way.

Log messages with -verbose option for both mpich2-1.4.1 and mpich3.0.4 can be found at

MPICH2-1.4.1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6sgkarmsi5vrdfd/RAMS-mpich2-1.4.1.log?dl=0
MPICH3.0.4: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxvl5q6dy03pgew/RAMS-mpich2-3.0.4.log?dl=0

cpi example runs fine with both mpich instances

Thanks in advance for your help and best regards

**EDIT 1** Added head of log file

```
[paco@Llamp RUN]$ time ../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/mpirun -verbose -machinefile mpd.hosts -n 20 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN
host: llamp
host: l2

==================================================================================================
mpiexec options:
----------------
  Base path: /export/RAMS/RUN/../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/
  Launcher: (null)
  Debug level: 1
  Enable X: -1

  Global environment:
  -------------------
    XDG_SESSION_ID=1376
    HOSTNAME=Llamp
    SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
    TERM=xterm-256color
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    HISTSIZE=1000
    SSH_CLIENT=193.144.100.32 35848 22
    SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
    QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3
    QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include
    SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
    QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1
    USER=paco
    LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
    MAIL=/var/spool/mail/paco
    PATH=/export/RAMS/misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin:/export/RAMS/misc/hdf5-1.8.9/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/paco/.local/bin:/home/paco/bin
    PWD=/export/RAMS/RUN
    LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
    MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
    LOADEDMODULES=
    SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
    HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
    SHLVL=1
    HOME=/home/paco
    LOGNAME=paco
    QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib
    SSH_CONNECTION=193.144.100.32 35848 193.144.100.45 22
    MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules
    LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1003
    BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}
    _=../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/mpirun
    OLDPWD=/export/RAMS

  Hydra internal environment:
  ---------------------------
    GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_PRECONNECTED=y


    Proxy information:
    *********************
      [1] proxy: llamp (1 cores)
      Exec list: ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); 

      [2] proxy: l2 (1 cores)
      Exec list: ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); ./rams-6.2.03 (1 processes); 


==================================================================================================

[mpiexec@Llamp] Timeout set to -1 (-1 means infinite)
[mpiexec@Llamp] Got a control port string of llamp:32814

Proxy launch args: /export/RAMS/RUN/../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy --control-port llamp:32814 --debug --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --proxy-id 

[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI FD: (null); PMI PORT: (null); PMI ID/RANK: -1
Arguments being passed to proxy 0:
--version 1.4.1 --iface-ip-env-name MPICH_INTERFACE_HOSTNAME --hostname llamp --global-core-map 0,1,1 --filler-process-map 0,1,1 --global-process-count 20 --auto-cleanup 1 --pmi-rank -1 --pmi-kvsname kvs_29606_0 --pmi-process-mapping (vector,(0,2,1)) --ckpoint-num -1 --global-inherited-env 33 'XDG_SESSION_ID=1376' 'HOSTNAME=Llamp' 'SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=' 'TERM=xterm-256color' 'SHELL=/bin/bash' 'HISTSIZE=1000' 'SSH_CLIENT=193.144.100.32 35848 22' 'SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=' 'QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3' 'QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include' 'SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0' 'QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1' 'USER=paco' 'LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:' 'MAIL=/var/spool/mail/paco' 'PATH=/export/RAMS/misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin:/export/RAMS/misc/hdf5-1.8.9/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/paco/.local/bin:/home/paco/bin' 'PWD=/export/RAMS/RUN' 'LANG=es_ES.UTF-8' 'MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles' 'LOADEDMODULES=' 'SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=' 'HISTCONTROL=ignoredups' 'SHLVL=1' 'HOME=/home/paco' 'LOGNAME=paco' 'QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib' 'SSH_CONNECTION=193.144.100.32 35848 193.144.100.45 22' 'MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules' 'LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s' 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1003' 'BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}' '_=../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/mpirun' 'OLDPWD=/export/RAMS' --global-user-env 0 --global-system-env 1 'GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_PRECONNECTED=y' --proxy-core-count 1 --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN 

[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI FD: (null); PMI PORT: (null); PMI ID/RANK: -1
Arguments being passed to proxy 1:
--version 1.4.1 --iface-ip-env-name MPICH_INTERFACE_HOSTNAME --hostname l2 --global-core-map 1,1,0 --filler-process-map 1,1,0 --global-process-count 20 --auto-cleanup 1 --pmi-rank -1 --pmi-kvsname kvs_29606_0 --pmi-process-mapping (vector,(0,2,1)) --ckpoint-num -1 --global-inherited-env 33 'XDG_SESSION_ID=1376' 'HOSTNAME=Llamp' 'SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=' 'TERM=xterm-256color' 'SHELL=/bin/bash' 'HISTSIZE=1000' 'SSH_CLIENT=193.144.100.32 35848 22' 'SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=' 'QTDIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3' 'QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include' 'SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0' 'QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED=1' 'USER=paco' 'LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:' 'MAIL=/var/spool/mail/paco' 'PATH=/export/RAMS/misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin:/export/RAMS/misc/hdf5-1.8.9/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/paco/.local/bin:/home/paco/bin' 'PWD=/export/RAMS/RUN' 'LANG=es_ES.UTF-8' 'MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles' 'LOADEDMODULES=' 'SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=' 'HISTCONTROL=ignoredups' 'SHLVL=1' 'HOME=/home/paco' 'LOGNAME=paco' 'QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib' 'SSH_CONNECTION=193.144.100.32 35848 193.144.100.45 22' 'MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules' 'LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s' 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1003' 'BASH_FUNC_module()=() {  eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}' '_=../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/mpirun' 'OLDPWD=/export/RAMS' --global-user-env 0 --global-system-env 1 'GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_PRECONNECTED=y' --proxy-core-count 1 --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN --exec --exec-appnum 0 --exec-proc-count 1 --exec-local-env 0 --exec-wdir /export/RAMS/RUN --exec-args 3 ./rams-6.2.03 -f RAMSIN 

[mpiexec@Llamp] Launch arguments: /export/RAMS/RUN/../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy --control-port llamp:32814 --debug --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --proxy-id 0 
[mpiexec@Llamp] Launch arguments: /usr/bin/ssh -x l2 "/export/RAMS/RUN/../misc/mpich2-1.4.1/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy" --control-port llamp:32814 --debug --rmk user --launcher ssh --demux poll --pgid 0 --retries 10 --proxy-id 1 
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 0): init
pmi_version=1 pmi_subversion=1 
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] PMI response: cmd=response_to_init pmi_version=1 pmi_subversion=1 rc=0
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 6): init
pmi_version=1 pmi_subversion=1 
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] PMI response: cmd=response_to_init pmi_version=1 pmi_subversion=1 rc=0
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 8): init
pmi_version=1 pmi_subversion=1 
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] PMI response: cmd=response_to_init pmi_version=1 pmi_subversion=1 rc=0
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 0): get_maxes

[proxy:0:0@Llamp] PMI response: cmd=maxes kvsname_max=256 keylen_max=64 vallen_max=1024
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 6): get_maxes

[proxy:0:0@Llamp] PMI response: cmd=maxes kvsname_max=256 keylen_max=64 vallen_max=1024
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 0): get_appnum

[proxy:0:0@Llamp] PMI response: cmd=appnum appnum=0
[proxy:0:0@Llamp] got pmi command (from 8): get_maxes
```

**EDIT 2** Added tail of log file

```
 00001116000000   ./geodata/ndh-N-0000-11-16-000000-g3.h5
 00001216120000   ./geodata/ndh-N-0000-12-16-120000-g3.h5
 ------------------------------------------------------
 Surface, topo, sst, and ndvi files all ok for
    RUNTYPE = INITIAL
   Initial start:INITIAL                     2

[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 25: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 25): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 5): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 7): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 10): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 5: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 13): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 16): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 19): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] got pmi command (from 22): get
kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard 
[proxy:0:1@l2] forwarding command (cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard) upstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 7: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 10: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 13: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 16: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 19: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[mpiexec@Llamp] [pgid: 0] got PMI command: cmd=get kvsname=kvs_29606_0 key=P0-businesscard
[mpiexec@Llamp] PMI response to fd 7 pid 22: cmd=get_result rc=0 msg=success value=description#llamp$port#53500$ifname#192.168.2.101$
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
[proxy:0:1@l2] we don't understand the response get_result; forwarding downstream
```

**EDIT 3**

```
ifconfig -a  LLAMP

enp5s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 38:d5:47:99:8d:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xc6200000-c627ffff  

enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 193.144.100.45  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 193.144.100.255
        inet6 fe80::c586:920:4d0d:b72e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:d5:47:99:8d:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6054655  bytes 852521221 (813.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 79434  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2776240  bytes 3945364551 (3.6 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xc6100000-c617ffff  

ens2f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::3fcf:81c8:d9d3:276b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:97:f6:5b:48:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2269948483  bytes 3155530639905 (2.8 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2271491960  bytes 3147155639055 (2.8 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 26  memory 0xc3000000-c37fffff  

ens2f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 34:97:f6:5b:48:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25911443  bytes 37100250017 (34.5 GiB)
        RX errors 506  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 506
        TX packets 25917681  bytes 37113403100 (34.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 55  memory 0xc2000000-c27fffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 174114  bytes 59215534 (56.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 174114  bytes 59215534 (56.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:50:f8:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:50:f8:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0




ifconfig -a L2
  enp5s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 38:d5:47:9a:60:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xc6200000-c627ffff  

enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 38:d5:47:9a:60:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xc6100000-c617ffff  

ens2f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::212e:6f32:3a10:915f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:d5:47:01:d2:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3040525097  bytes 4219639728177 (3.8 TiB)
        RX errors 1  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 1
        TX packets 3043720685  bytes 4232541936966 (3.8 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 26  memory 0xc3000000-c37fffff  

ens2f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 38:d5:47:01:d3:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 55  memory 0xc2000000-c27fffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20553  bytes 1664700 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20553  bytes 1664700 (1.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:2d:b7:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:2d:b7:b6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: [STAT](https://computing.llnl.gov/code/STAT/) is a tool to debug these kinds of issues. Can't download the logfiles from dropbox.

Comment: Hi @zulan Just added head and tail of log files. Will give a look at STAT toolm, thanks

Comment: It could be a networking issue. Make sure that there are no virtual interfaces on both nodes that share the same subnetwork address.

Comment: Post the output of `ifconfig -a` or `ip address show` on both machines.

Comment: Hi @HristoIliev Added the output of ifconfig and sorry for the delay.

Comment: Both nodes seem to have a virtual bridge network interface `virbr0` with IP `192.168.122.1/24`. This confuses some MPI implementations that try to use all available interfaces for communication. Try telling the library to ignore `virbr0`. I know how to prevent Open MPI from using it, but for MPICH2/3 you should look up the documentation.

Comment: Hi @HristoIliev I have tried to run with `-iface ens2f0` but could not succeed. Can you give a hint to prevent using `virbr0` in Open MPI, I can't find how to do it for MPICH, so I can look for something similar

Comment: Output of `mpirun -iface ens2f0 ...` can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8lmiqwfrkl7iks/mpi-output.txt?dl=0)

Comment: With Open MPI it boils down to passing `--mca btl_tcp_if_include ens2f0 --mca oob_tcp_if_include ens2f0` to `mpiexec`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15073717/1374437) for more details.