# MPI - Is there a limit of informations that can be sent beetween nodes?

Tags: c, mpi, limit, scatter

I'm having some trouble sending a (very long) string between nodes in MPI.

My goal is to use MPI_Scatterv to send different pieces of this very long string from process 0, to all the other processes.
The program I wrote works fine, but when **the size of the string to be sent exceeds 196255 characters**, I get this error:

```
[node1][[46392,1],0][btl_tcp_endpoint.c:803:mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect] connect() to 10.0.2.15 failed: Connection refused (111)
```

This happens the first time I try to run it, but if I try again, I get this other error message:

```
Open MPI detected an inbound MPI TCP connection request from a peer
that appears to be part of this MPI job (i.e., it identified itself as
part of this Open MPI job), but it is from an IP address that is
unexpected.  This is highly unusual.

The inbound connection has been dropped, and the peer should simply
try again with a different IP interface (i.e., the job should
hopefully be able to continue).

  Local host:          node1
  Local PID:           3143
  Peer hostname:       node1 ([[46370,1],0])
  Source IP of socket: 10.0.2.15
  Known IPs of peer:
```

I don't exactly know why this is happening, so I don't know if I can fix it, or if there are some limitations, I'd like to know why there are and how to spot them.

In case this information is useful to identify the problem, my string is allocated dynamically, first with a calloc and it is reallocated with a realloc when I need to.

Furthermore, my MPI environment consists of 3 nodes, which are 3 VM, brought up with vagrant. Each VM has 1024 MB of memory.

I run my program with: *mpirun -np 3 --host node1,node2,node3 --mca btl_base_warn_component_unused 0 ./program*

In case you need to see the code, just ask, I'll post it. I haven't posted it yet because I'm not sure if it's needed.

Thank you!

Comment: That’s likely unrelated. Try `mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 ...` instead (replace `eth0` with the name of the interface to be used for MPI communications.

Comment: Thank you @GillesGouaillardet that solved my problem! Now it works even with a string whose size is bigger than 196255 characters. You really saved me! Could also tell me how you came to that conclusion? I wanna learn! Thank you very much :)

Comment: It is a known issue with Open MPI and there are many questions here - just paste "mca_btl_tcp_endpoint_complete_connect" into the search field. When the library is using TCP to transport messages, it tries to make use of all network connections the nodes have. But often there are configured virtual or other adaptors on different nodes that share the same IP network but provide no actual connectivity between them and Open MPI gets into trouble. I wrote a longer description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073717/1374437). As to Gilles, he knows Open MPI inside and out :D